# react-test-renderer shallow renderer is not available in production mode

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, gitlab-ci, enzyme

I have this error in all tests in the gitlab test pipeline but locally all tests passes. Maybe I'm missing some environment variable or has something to do with Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() }) ?

npm task:

```
"test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
```

scripts/test.js:

```
'use strict'

const jest = require('jest')

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  throw err
})

const argv = process.argv.slice(2)

// Watch unless on CI or in coverage mode
if (!process.env.CI && argv.indexOf('--coverage') < 0) {
  argv.push('--watch')
}

jest.run(argv)
```

Gitlab console error:

```
$ node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom
FAIL src/components/ui/Grid/__tests__/Grid.spec.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    shallow renderer is not available in production mode.
        at Error (native)

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-test-renderer/shallow.js:4:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:21:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/index.js:2:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/ui/Grid/__tests__/Grid.spec.jsx:3:27)
```

Grid.spec.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import Grid from '../index'

const { Row, Column } = Grid
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe('Grid', () => {
  it('should have a Row and a Column', () => {
    expect(Grid.Row).toBeDefined()
    expect(Grid.Column).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered that NODE_ENV was not being set to 'test' or 'development' (something other than 'production')

Comment: HI I am having the exact same issue. Where did you set NODE_ENV value?